# WooCommerce don't send email when order status changed to a custom status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I created a new order status using `register_post_status()` and added it to list of WC Order statuses using `wc_order_statuses` hook

Now I'm building a plugin to send an email when the order changed to this custom status, called production:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_production', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: That looks like it should work.  maybe try moving your action to the `woocommerce_order_status_changed` hook and then filtering for the 'to' action.  it's not pretty but it should work.

Comment: @mrben522 nothing changed. I add an error log to trigger function and it not show.

Comment: so the `woocommerce_order_status_changed` hook isn't firing at all?   Interesting.  Try var dumping `->get_valid_statuses()` on the order object and see if your order status is on there.  It sounds like your status change might be failing before it gets to the transition function where that hook lives.

Comment: @mrben522 I add a `woocommerce_order_status_changed` hook on my theme and in plugin. But only on theme it return a log. It's look like this hook on plugin is not called. I'm testing this with an existing order, not a new order. I don't known if this make any difference.